# Airflow - Task flow, Dynamic Task Mapping with multiple output

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x, airflow-taskflow

Let's say I have an Airflow (2.3) DAG that looks like this:

```py
@task
def retrieve_ingest_setup_queries():
    settings = Variable.get("athena_settings", deserialize_json=True)
    # settings = {'drops': ["DROP TABLE my_table", "DROP TABLE my_table2"],
    #             'creates': ["CREATE TABLE ...", ...]}
    return settings

@dag(
    dag_id='athena_something',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval=None,
    render_template_as_native_obj=True,
)
def somedag():
    ingest_setup = retrieve_ingest_setup_queries()

    ingest_db_setup_drops = AthenaOperator.partial(
        task_id='db_drops',
        database="{{ var.json.athena.database }}",
        output_location="{{ var.json.athena.output_location }}",
        aws_conn_id='aws_athena'
    ).expand(query=ingest_setup??????)

    ingest_db_setup_creates = AthenaOperator.partial(
        task_id='db_creates',
        database="{{ var.json.athena.database }}",
        output_location="{{ var.json.athena.output_location }}",
        aws_conn_id='aws_athena'
    ).expand(query=ingest_setup??????)
```

I am looking for a way to set "query" in the expand method as ingest_setup['drops'] for my first operator and as ingest_setup['creates'] for the second.

I could use two different retrieval functions, but I'd like to use only one.
I want to use taskflow if at all possible.
Expand doesn't support templating, so I don't see how/if this can be done (see ?????? in the code).

Comment: I think that you're missing the function definition your `@dag` should be decorating. i.e: `@dag(...)
def example_dag():`

Comment: fixed it, technically I should call it at the end too but it's not really relevant to what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to use multiple_outputs=True for the task decorator.
Then ingest_setup['creates'] works as intended.

This only works with task decorators though, accessing the key of a dictionary that's an operator's result (XComArg) is far from intuitive. It is discussed [here](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/16618).

From there, I have created the following class for operator results:

```
class XcomDict:
    def __init__(self, operator: Operator):
        self.operator_output = str(operator.output).strip("{ }")

    def __getitem__(self, item: str):
        return f"{{{{ {self.operator_output}['{item}'] }}}}"
```

Of course, it assumes the operator's return value is a dictionary. I use it this way:

```
    job = CreateJobOperator(
        task_id='create_job', ...)

    wait = WaiForJobOperator(
        task_id='wait_for_job_to_complete',
        job_id=XcomDict(job)['JobId'],..)
```